# Its possible load my progress bars only when i click in the link for my div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a link to my `div` `mySkills`, and when I access my page I have the bars loaded, but I just want to load my progress bars when i click in my `href` to this `div` `mySkills`.
How can we do that?

```
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>        
        <li ><a href="#About">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#mySkills">Skills</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#form">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav> 

<div class="mySkills">
    <h1>John <span>Skills</span></h1>
    <div class="skill">
        <h6>HTML</h6>
        <div class="progress_bar orange">
            <div style="width: 75%;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="skill">
        <h6>CSS</h6>
        <div class="progress_bar teal">
            <div style="width: 67%;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="skill">
        <h6>Photoshop</h6>
        <div class="progress_bar blue">
            <div style="width: 80%;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="skill">
        <h6>PHP</h6>
        <div class="progress_bar green">
            <div style="width: 55%;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="skill">
        <h6>Javascript</h6>
        <div class="progress_bar yellow">
            <div style="width: 55%;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your '<a>' href link tag?

Comment: Thanks for answer, i update my post with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible approach to your request:

http://jsfiddle.net/pHyz9/

**HTML added:**

```
<button id="update">Update Values</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
.skill {
    display: none;
}

.progress_bar div {
    transition: width 1s;
}
```

**Javascript (jQuery):**

```
$("#update").on("click", function(){
    $(".skill").fadeIn(800);
    $(".orange div").css("width", "75%");
    $(".teal div").css("width", "67%");
    $(".blue div").css("width", "80%");
    $(".green div").css("width", "55%");
    $(".yellow div").css("width", "55%");
});
```

It uses CSS3, it is a bit incomplete, and the code could be prettier, but this is only an example to show what can be done with such a simple code.

Answer (score 2):

So you should take following steps in order to achieve your goal.

Steps:

`1`. Make your `<div class="mySkills">` hidden using css.

```
div.mySkills
{
  display:none;
}
```

`2`. And on `<a href="#mySkills">Skills</a>`

```
$('a[href="#mySkills"]').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault;
  e.stopPropagation;

  $('div.mySkills').toggle();
});
```

More about .toggle() you can read from [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

P.S.: If I understand correctly your question and answer in properly replay with comments. I will correct it.

> If you want to see working example open following [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Ug4GY/).

Comment: Step 1 should be in separate css file or inside of style tag.
Step 2 should be in separate js file which will be loaded after jquery and when document is ready. Or in your html file before closing tag of body put script tag and inside you should put document.ready handler inside you should put code for step 2.

Comment: I update and of my answer and there are working example just look it and response is it what you want?

Comment: I think I explained myself badly, sorry. I wnat that when I click the "skills" link i want to go to div "mySkills" and then want to see the bars to do the load in that moment that i arrive in mySkills div!

Comment: Thank you for your help!But what iwas looking for was about what antindexer post.

Comment: If you got your help and response, it is good for you. So it is just begining of your question asking journey. So nobody is perfect. It is ok. I hope you will improve your skills soon. :)